# How can I obtain the output of an intermediate layer (feature extraction)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, feature-extraction

I want to extract features of a  optical image and save them into numpy array . I've seen similar questions , also can be seen here : https://keras.io/getting_started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer-feature-extraction , but don't know how to go about it .

Comment: What is exactly the problem you have with those examples?

Answer (score 2):

Keras documentation does exaclty specify how to do that. If you have defined your model `model_full` you can create another one, that is just a part of it - from the input layer, to the one you're interested in.

```
model_part = Model(
  inputs=model_full.input,
  outputs=model_full.get_layer("intermed_layer").output)
```

Then you should be able to obtain output from intermediate layer using:

```
intermed_output = model_part(data)
```

In order to do that, you just need a `model_full` defined, which I assume you already have.

#### 2nd approach

You can also use built-in Keras function, which I guess you already saw in documentation as well. It may look kind of complicated at first, but it's just creating a function with bound values i.e.

```
from keras import backend as K

get_3rd_layer_output = K.function(
  [model.layers[0].input], # param 1 will be treated as layer[0].output
  [model.layers[3].output]) # and this function will return output from 3rd layer

# here X is param 1 (input) and the function returns output from layers[3]
output = get_3rd_layer_output([X])[0]
```

Clearly, again `model` has to be defined. Not sure if there are any other requirements apart from that.

Comment: I'm guessing using a relu model to extract features from jpg and then save them into a numpy array